# DrawingVisual performance with Opacity=0

Tags: wpf

If I have a DrawingVisual in WPF with Opacity=0, is that enough for it not to be drawn? We have hundreds of DrawingVisuals on a Canvas, and are currently setting Opacity=0 on the visuals that are not to be displayed, and I wanted to make sure there is no rendering performance hit for rendering a DrawingVisual with Opacity=0.

UPDATE: I have discovered through testing that there IS overhead when Opacity=0, but since DrawingVisual doesn't have a Visibility property, I don't know how else you would tell it to not be displayed unless you actualy remove it from the visual tree, so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient seems to be setting the opacity in my tests. Another simple approach is to redraw the visuals that are affected.

```
using (DrawingContext dc = RenderOpen()) {} //Hide this visual
```

And then redraw when they become visible again.

Rendering a blank drawingcontext seems to be very quick. But if you have complicated visuals it could take time to rerender them when they become visible.

Answer (score 3):

I solved a very similar problem by using a [`DrawingGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawinggroup) and adding or removing [`Drawing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawing) objects from the `DrawingGroup` as they either needed to be displayed or hidden. The key is to organize your `Drawing` objects in such a way that they are easy to manage and to understand how to add and remove them from the `DrawingGroup`.

Remember that you want to add and remove the `Drawing` objects from the [`DrawingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawinggroup.children) exposed by the  [`DrawingGroup.Children`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcollection) property.  So use [`DrawingGroup.Children.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcollection.add) or the other `DrawingCollection` methods: [`Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcollection.insert), [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcollection.remove), [`RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcollection.removeat), [`Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcollection.clear).  You will need to keep an external list of the `Drawing` objects you add/remove to the `DrawingGroup` to do this successfully.

I used this technique to great effect by drawing an Image (bitmap) into the first child in my instance of `DrawingGroup` and then adding and removing `Drawing` objects to this instance of `DrawingGroup` in order to layer polygons, paths, text, etc on top of the drawing.

I "draw" or "erase" on the image by adding or removing `Drawing` objects to the instance of the `DrawingGroup`.  The `DrawingGroup` is treated as a single `Drawing` and so any scaling, panning, or other manipulations will affect all `Drawing` objects within the `DrawingGroup`.

Comment: This is outstanding. I had suspected this radically different way of drawing would work in WPF, and your post encouraged me to try it. As you say, the key is to plan carefully, but the performance is outstanding. Prepare an arbitrarily deep nesting of `DrawingGroup`s to represent the possible collapse/expand/etc states of your scene. You only call `RenderOpen()` once, when you initialize, with the single call `dc.DrawDrawing(dg)` on the root of your tree. From here on, you can just edit/manipulate the tree (and its childrens' transforms)--WPF tracks and updates everything automatically.

Comment: Just to be clear again on how amazing this is; you can freely add and remove drawings from—or modify transforms on—any deeply-buried `DrawingGroup` or `Drawing` in the hierarchy and the display is immediately updated. You don't need to request or force rendering. In fact, because this type of change is handled automatically by the lower-level [DWM/Milcore](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/greg_schechter/2006/03/19/dwms-use-of-directx-gpus-and-hardware-acceleration/) layer, if the outermost bounds haven't changed then WPF itself doesn't participate in (or possibly even notice) the change, ,

Comment: @GlennSlayden It looks amazing and I'd like to do it, but I can't make it work... I have one root `DrawingGroup` with two different `DrawingGroups`: one for static elements (S), and one for moving elements (M). However, when a `Geometry`'s `Transform` is updated in (M), it looks like the whole root `DrawingGroup` (S+M) is redrawn by the lower-level layer... (I can see it thanks to WPF Performance Suite's Perforator's dirty regions). The bounds encapsulate all the drawings.

Comment: @Drarig29 If you need intermediate transforms, you must anticipate this and nest one or more additional `DrawingGroup`(s) in your `Drawing` hierarchy beforehand, so that you have an independent/dedicated `Transform` property that only affects its own children, those that later require the specific (sub-)transform. Similar to what I mentioned above, changes to a `Transform` at any buried level of depth take effect immediately, without requiring any additional layout passes or `Render()` calls. Obviously, you have to retain the handles to the inner `DrawingGroup` objects yourself separately.

Comment: @Drarig29 Also, 'Bounds' changes immediately anytime you a.) apply a `Transform` or b.) change the `Children` of the `DrawingGroup`, so you need to think carefully about the order you do things if you're calculating a transform based on child bounds. If necessary, make a local copy of the initial `Rect` value-type so that such calculations don't get ruined as you add children to the `DrawingGroup`, but more likely, since the transform will uniformly apply to all of the children, having their respective individual bounds' factor into their (joint) parent's `Transform` indicates a design flaw.

Comment: Thank you Glenn for editing this and making the answer much better!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to check would be to instead set the [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx) to Visibility.Colapsed, and see if there's any drawing performance differences.

Visibility.Colapsed ensures that the element is not visible but also that it will not participate in the Arrange, Measure and Render passes of the UI, while an element with Opacity=0 might participate in all passes.

Comment: The question was about DrawingVisual which has no Visibility property. This answer is valid for UIElement calss.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply remove the visual from the visual children list? When it needs to be visible you add it back.